# Set ListBox SelectedItems based on another collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I have a `ListBox` that is bound to `MyCollection` of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

I have another `List<string>` `SubCollection` that contains a subset of `MyCollection`

Whenever `SubCollection` changes, I'd like the `SelectedItems` to be highlighted as per the `SubCollection`

Is there any `Binding`, `Behaviour` or any other way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Let's say I have a `ListBox` bound to `MyCollection` `{ "Orange", "Mango", "Stawberry", "Pineapple" }`

Let's assume that I press a button to load data from a database and the result is "Orange", "Mango" which is then placed into to `SubCollection`. `ListBox` should now have "Orange", "Mango" as its `SelectedItems`.

Comment: Have you tried to (multi)bind IsSelected property of ListBoxItem to the MyCollection current object and the whole SubCollection? It will return true/false if SubCollection.Contains(current)

Comment: IsSelected property of List?

Comment: This property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "SubCollection changes"? Can you please give us an example.

Comment: @Haritha, Updated the question with scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `List` `AttachedProperty` for the `ListBox` that adds items to the `ListBox.SelectedItems` when the list is changed.

The `AttachedProperty` solution keeps `WPF` clean and your `MVVM` pattern, Also it makes this feature reusable thoughout all your projects :)

Here is an example:

### AttachedProperty:

```
public static class ListBoxExtensions
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SearchValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemList", typeof(IList), typeof(ListBoxExtensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemListChanged)));

    public static IList GetSelectedItemList(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemListProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItemList(DependencyObject obj, IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemListProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = d as ListBox;
        if (listbox != null)
        {
            listbox.SelectedItems.Clear();
            var selectedItems = e.NewValue as IList;
            if (selectedItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in selectedItems)
                {
                    listbox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Xaml Usage:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple"
         local:ListBoxExtensions.SelectedItemList="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```

---

---

### Demo:

Working example if you want to test:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication17.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication17"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="227" Width="170" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 local:ListBoxExtensions.SelectedItemList="{Binding SelectedItems}"  Margin="0,0,0,37"   >
                 <ListBox.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                          </Trigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                 </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Populate SelectedItemList" Click="Button_Click" Height="32" Margin="2,0,1,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication17
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<string> _selectedItems = new List<string>();
        private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string> 
        { "Orange", "Mango", "Stawberry", "Pineapple", "Apple", "Grape", "Banana" };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }

        public List<string> SelectedItems
        {
            get { return _selectedItems; }
            set { _selectedItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItems"); }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedItems = new List<string> { "Orange", "Pineapple", "Apple" };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
        }
    }

    public static class ListBoxExtensions
    {
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SearchValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemList", typeof(IList), typeof(ListBoxExtensions),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemListChanged)));

        public static IList GetSelectedItemList(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemListProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedItemList(DependencyObject obj, IList value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectedItemListProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listbox = d as ListBox;
            if (listbox != null)
            {
                listbox.SelectedItems.Clear();
                var selectedItems = e.NewValue as IList;
                if (selectedItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in selectedItems)
                    {
                        listbox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is Perfect , but Just one more question, When I select manually , the selected item comes up as blue , but now this light gray . Can we over ride this?\

Comment: The selection is gray because the listbox is not focused after you press the button, I have added a fix to the demo above, it just sets the Inactive listbox colors to the same as the focused colors

Comment: Type 'SystemColors' does not contain a static member named 'InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey'.

I am targetting .NET Framework 4.0 , but InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey targets for v4.5

Comment: And I also changed the Key to Hardcoded values like 1 and 2 , but still the color is not changing !

Comment: try ` <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />`

Comment: Marking this as answer as ,this one is the Cleanest One. Other answers were helpful though

Comment: added .NET4 solution to the Demo above :)

Comment: I do not know if you are viewing this still, but, would this work for ListBox that is contained as <DataTemplate>? I am trying to use this just like you are on above demo; however, even thought the selection change has occured, any of the 3 methods are not being called. I can see the dependencyproperty call is being processed.

Answer (score 5):

I have a suggestion for you.

You can bind to the "`IsSelected`" property of the `ListBoxItem`.

To do that you have to use a `collection of objects`(let's say `MyListBoxItem`) instead of collection of strings.

```cs
public class  MyListBoxItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Use this "`IsSelected`" property of the `MyListBoxItem` class to bind the "`IsSelected`" property of the `ListBoxItem`.

Ex: In you view model,

```cs
this.MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>();

MyListBoxItem item1 = new MyListBoxItem()
item1.Description = "Mango";
item1.IsSelected = true;
MyCollection .add(item1);

MyListBoxItem item2 = new MyListBoxItem()
item2 .Description = "Orange";
item2 .IsSelected = false;
MyCollection .add(item2 );
```

XAML (Inside the `ListBox`)

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Why the Description  required in this case?

Comment: @Simsons: Please look at the answer again. I have modified. I have described the use of Description property.

Comment: Tried with sample application , this is working fine. Will update you once implementation successful on actual application

Answer (score 2):

The standard data binding doesn’t work, because the SelectedItems property is read-only.

One simple approach, is to manually iterate the MyCollection and Set the IsSelected Property of each item, based on the items in SubCollection.
For this, the items in MyCollection list should contain objects inherited from ListBoxItem which would expose the IsSelected Property.

***Here is a sample WPF app to demostrate it :***

The button click would update the selected items based on items in SubCollection list. For now I have hardcode the values of  SubCollection list.

Based on you implementation you could update your SubCollection, and hook the code inside button click event to any other events appropriately.(like  make SubCollection list as ObservableCollection and hook to ObservableCollection.CollectionChange)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="255">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="10,10"/>
            <Button Content="UpdateSelection"  Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem>() { new MyListBoxItem("Orange"), new MyListBoxItem("Mango"), new MyListBoxItem("Stawberry"), new MyListBoxItem("Pineapple") };

            //Items to be selected on this.MyCollection ListBox
            this.SubCollection = new List<string>() { "Pineapple", "Mango" };

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem> _myCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItem> MyCollection
        {
            get { return _myCollection; }
            set
            {
                this._myCollection = value;
            }
        }

        public IList<string> SubCollection { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear all the selected items in the ListBox
            this.MyCollection.ToList().ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = false);

            // SELECT only the items in MySubCollection into this.MyCollection ListBox
            this.MyCollection.Where(item => this.SubCollection.Contains(item.Content.ToString())).ToList().ForEach(item => item.IsSelected= true);
        }
    }

    public class MyListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
    {
        public MyListBoxItem(string displayName)
        {
            this.Content = displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Simsons: You were able to try/use it?

Comment: Tried it , Working fine , but I need to change my data structure , which need to be avoided . What U Say?

Comment: @Simsons: You mean updating MyCollection List from List<string> to a List<MyListBoxItem> ??

Comment: Yes, There is Service which returns values after as List<strinng> , so I can not change that , in turn what I have to is iterate and update the new MyListBoxItem object

Comment: Ok, in that case I would recommend @sa_ddam213 answer. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check this blogpost: [how-to-databind-to-selecteditems](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html). There is a demo project with code attached.

Answer (score 1):

Use "`SelectedValue`" property of the ListBox. 
(Because you are using collection of string to bind the List Box.)

1. Define a string type property in your view model (let's say `MySelectedValue`).
2. Then Bind it to the "`SelectedValue`" property of the both List Boxes. (Remeber to set the `Mode = TwoWay` in your Main ListBox)
3. Let's say a method will execute when you select an item in Sub collection List Box. (You have to trigger the `SelectionChanged` event of the Sub Collection ListBox)
4. That's it.

> So. You have to do is:
>
> Use same property to bind the "SelectedValue" property of the BOTH
>   List Boxes.

Let's say if you wanna bind a collection of objects to the List Box.
Then use `SelectedItem` property to achieve this task.

Comment: This is Just a single listbox, not two separate listbox. I want to select the ListBox items depending upon the SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

in case you know the index number you want to select, you can use

```
int[] index = {1, 2, 5};
for( int i in index) 
{    
   listBox.SetSelected( i, true );
}
```